# How to put large chunk of code in AlertController block (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uialertcontroller

In my collection view cell, I have a button which successfully saves the current user (PFUser) to an array of users of each event (which are the objects at index path).

However, I would like to add an alert view, but have been unsuccessful in putting the enormous chunk of code inside the alert action block. I suppose I could create another method but I feel there's a simpler way to do it.

When I tried putting it in, A. the sheer number of brackets threw me off a bit and B. it didn't recognize "alertController" anymore at the bottom of the method.

Thanks for the help like always.

```
func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview
    let cell = view?.superview as! EventCell
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)

//        print(indexPath)

    if let indexPath = indexPath {
        if let event = events?[indexPath.row] {

            //pops alert vc

            var alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: event.eventTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            let saveUserToEvent = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { _ in



                // WHAT TO DO HERE? I want to add the stuff below


            }

            alertController.addAction(saveUserToEvent)

            var attendees = [String]()
            if let attendeesTmp = event["attendees"] as?[String] {
                attendees = attendeesTmp;
            }
            if let objId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {
                var found = false
                for objIdd in attendees {
                    if objIdd == objId {
                        found = true
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if !found {
                    attendees.append(objId)
                    event["attendees"] = attendees;
                    event.saveInBackground()
                }
            }

            if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
                var eventsAttending = [String]()
                if let eventsAttendingTmp = user["eventsToAttend"] as?[String] {
                    eventsAttending = eventsAttendingTmp;
                }
                if let eventId = event.objectId {
                    var found = false
                    for eventIdd in eventsAttending {
                        if eventIdd == eventId {
                            found = true
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if !found {
                    eventsAttending.append(eventId)
                    user["eventsToAttend"] = eventsAttending;
                    user.saveInBackground()
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put

```
alertController.addAction(saveUserToEvent)
```

In the brackets as well? It stays outside.

This should work

```
    func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let button = sender as! UIButton
    let view = button.superview
    let cell = view?.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(cell)

    //        print(indexPath)

    if let indexPath = indexPath {
        if let event = events?[indexPath.row] {

            //pops alert vc

            var alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: event.eventTitle, message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

            let saveUserToEvent = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { _ in



                var attendees = [String]()
                if let attendeesTmp = event["attendees"] as?[String] {
                    attendees = attendeesTmp;
                }
                if let objId = PFUser.currentUser()?.objectId {
                    var found = false
                    for objIdd in attendees {
                        if objIdd == objId {
                            found = true
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if !found {
                        attendees.append(objId)
                        event["attendees"] = attendees;
                        event.saveInBackground()
                    }
                }

                if let user = PFUser.currentUser() {
                    var eventsAttending = [String]()
                    if let eventsAttendingTmp = user["eventsToAttend"] as?[String] {
                        eventsAttending = eventsAttendingTmp;
                    }
                    if let eventId = event.objectId {
                        var found = false
                        for eventIdd in eventsAttending {
                            if eventIdd == eventId {
                                found = true
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if !found {
                            eventsAttending.append(eventId)
                            user["eventsToAttend"] = eventsAttending;
                            user.saveInBackground()
                        }

                    }
                }


            }

            alertController.addAction(saveUserToEvent)


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Great thanks! I'll try it out once I fix all my iOS 9 errors and can build and run again. :)

Comment: @Echizzle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work